# How to query DictFields using mongoengine?

Tags: python, mongodb, pyramid, mongoengine, mongodb-query

I have created a MongoDB collection called lookup, in which I have 5 fields(`DictFields`).

I have the following code:

```
class Lookups(Document):
    industries = DictField()
    schools = DictField()
    qualifications = DictField()
    skills = DictField()
    fields_of_study = DictField()
```

And on another `.py` file I have:

```
from ..models.lookup import Lookups
industry = {}
for k in Lookups.objects:
    industry[k.industries] = k.industries    
print industry
```

This does not work. It outputs an empty dict: `{}`

I have also tried just printing out `k.industries`, but that returns nothing.

How can I query my `DictField`'s to get my desired result, which is to get the data from the `DictField`? Maybe I am structuring my Collection wrong?? I am new to `NoSQL` databases. 
I am using the [Pyrmaid](http://www.pylonsproject.org/) framework if it matters...

Comment: can you give Lookups.objects.count()?

Comment: It returns 0 `:/`... There is data in the Collection though... Why would it return `0` if there is data in my collection?

Comment: I guess you'are not connecting to the right db/collection.

Comment: I found my problem... its actually quite stupid... I named my collection: `lookup` and my class `lookups`. I just renamed my collection to be `lookups`...

Comment: Thanks for your response to my question `:)`